# Set QDockWidget border when docked and floating

Tags: qt, styles, qtstylesheets, qdockwidget

I'm trying to style my `QDockWidget` so that it has a border when docked and when floating.

I tried:

```
QDockWidget 
{
    border: 5px solid purple;
}
```

But this only produced a border when floating. When docked, the border just disappeared.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
QDockWidget > QWidget {
    border: 5px solid purple;
}
```

This is the result for the docked state:

[image]

This is the result for the undocked state:

[image]

Comment: I figured I was probably going to have to end up using this method. It's not exactly what I want since this is just styling the QWidget inside the QDockWidget and not the QDockWidget itself. Thanks though!

Comment: What does the > do and why does it work ?

Comment: @Dariusz `qss` uses the `css` syntax and `>` is called `child combinator`. See more on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator